# Provide custom configuration for Cassandra Debian package installation

Tags: cassandra

When doing a "apt install cassandra", Cassandra will start as a service with a default configuration.
Isn't there a way to provide a custom configuration, so that the service will start with the desired configuration, or install with service in stopped mode?

It seems a bit silly to have to stop service, change configuration, delete /var/lib/cassandra/* and finally restart service.